# c# List<object> to List<string>()

Tags: c#, cefsharp

**SOLUTION**
I've simply solved the problem with

```
    var list = (List<object>)response.Result;
                    List<List<object>> listOfListOfObjects = list.OfType<List<object>>().ToList();
                    for (var i = 0; i < listOfListOfObjects.Count; i++)
                    {
                        liste.Add((listOfListOfObjects[i])[2].ToString()); //[2] returns to me href, [1] returns innertext etc..  
                    }
```

Thanks to everyone!

**Problem**

I'm getting result from Script with List object but i want to analyse the result by putting it into string list and use IndexOf for searching keywords etc.
I've tried to use

```
var strings = (from o in objects
          select o.ToString()).ToList();
```

But it didn't work it converts items to just with name as "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" , it doesn't converts the exact items.

Here is my script code for cefsharp thanks to  @amaitland

```
const string script = @"(function()
                    {
                        var linksArray = new Array();
                        for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
                        {
                            linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML),
                                    String(document.links[i].innerText),
                                    String(document.links[i].href)];
                        }
                        return linksArray;
                    })();";

    browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var response = x.Result;

        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
        {
            var list = (List<object>)response.Result; // I want to put that "list" into listBox
```

Also result of script:
[image: Script Output]
[image: When i converted to string]

Comment: "it didn't work", unfortunately it did exactly what you asked of it, it called `.ToString()` on each of those objects. The issue, however, is that not all types overrides this method and thus uses the one inherited from `System.Object` which simply returns the type name of the object. If you want to do something else, you cannot use `ToString` alone. Since it seems you have a collection of lists of objects, what do you want each of those lists to turn into, a comma-separated string of the elements, for instance?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, Actually all i want to do is take seperate these [0] [1] [2] arrays into a 3 diffrent listboxes for collect them. They includes innerHtml, href etc so i need to store them in seprate listboxes, it will be in string type so i'll able to use IndexOf to get keywords from that listboxes. So i'm not interested in complex things like as seperate them  with comma etc. All i need to do is take items from object list and put them into simple string listbox

Comment: " take seperate these [0] [1] [2] arrays" is it always a list of 3 objects? can you rely on that?

Comment: As it tells you, each "object" in "objects" is actually a `List<object>` itself. So the first thing you could to is: `List<List<object>> listOfListOfObjects = objects.OfType<List<object>>().ToList();` -- then you can go check what the type of each of the "inner" objects in each list are. It looks like they are _probably_ always strings, but better check it.

Comment: @MongZhu yes as you see from script it just returns linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML),
                                    String(document.links[i].innerText),
                                    String(document.links[i].href)]; so there is always [0] to [2] arrays

Comment: Thanks now i got it bettter in this way you mean there are already some objects in each of my objectlist so i can't directly reach @Corak , also yea there is always strings in that object list but also some of the arrays are just "null" as you see from first pic ( just take a look on [0] and [1] . arrays

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a list of lists. If the inner lists contain values that can be shown as useful strings maybe you can comma separate them:

```
var listOfStrings = strings.Select(s => string.Join(", ", s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a list where each element is a list in and of itself.

Your cast to `List<object>` succeeds because the inner list (`List<object>`) in and of itself is an `object`. What you should be doing, however, is casting it to a `List<List<object>>`.

Right now you are calling `ToString()` on the inner lists (= the elements of the outer list), not the elements of the inner lists themselves.

It is unclear whether you intend to flatten this list or preserve the "list in list" nature of your data.

If you want to flatten it:

```
var outerList = (List<List<object>>) response.Result;

var allStringsInASingleList = outerList 
                                  .SelectMany(innerList => innerList)
                                  .Select(o => o.ToString())
                                  .ToList();
```

If you want to preserve the nested structure:

```
var outerList  = (List<List<object>>) response.Result;

var stringsInANestedList = outerList 
                                  .Select(innerList => 
                                      innerList.Select(o =>
                                          o.ToString()
                                      )
                                  )
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, yea now i got it why it returns me the name type of object, you mean i can't reach these elements because it already has list even in elements too. When i try to use both of your your advices it compiles fine but when i try to run app it crashes on var outerlist = .. the Exeption is "System.InvalidCastException: ''System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]]' '" . there are some "null" arrays on the objectlist, is this the reason of that crash??

Comment: @JustForss: It seems your "outer list" is actually an array (based on the JS code), so casting it to `List<Object>[]` (i.e. an array of lists) may be the solution.

Comment: @JustForss: But this is a very werid issue. Your code (casting it to `List<object>`) suggests that the outer collection is a list, and your debug watches show that the inner collections are of type `List<object>`. So that seems to me that the correct type should be `List<List<object>>`, but the invalid cast exception seems to contradict that. I can't debug your code for you. Debug it and figure out the type, so that you can then cast it appropriately.